# Fill in struct table

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
typedef struct bat {
  char * ch[30];
  int tp;
}
bat;



int main() {
  bat ba[5];
  ba = {
    {
      "Tropilleur", 2
    }, {
      "sous-marin", 3
    }, {
      "contre torpilleur", 3
    }, {
      "croiseur", 4
    }, {
      "porte avion", 5
    }
  };


  return 1;
}
```

> error: expected expression before '{' token
>     ba = {{"Tropilleur",2},
>   ^

Can anyone help with fill in a table of struct please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign an array with an initializer list after declaration.  If you combine your declaration with your initializer list, that should clear up your issue.

Additionally, check your struct definition, where you declare a pointer to a char array.  You will likely want a pointer or an array, not both in this case.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: The declaration is an array of char pointers (not a pointer to char array)